# react-grid-layout function in recursion

Tags: reactjs, recursion, react-grid-layout

I have a react project where I use react-grid-layout. I have an array (my layout) which looks more or less like this:

```
[
   {
      "w":9,
      "h":6,
      "x":0,
      "y":0,
      "i":"GridWrapper_6_4140d",
      "moved":false,
      "static":false,
      "children":[
         {
            "w":2,
            "h":2,
            "x":0,
            "y":0,
            "i":"SankeyChart_3_ea038",
            "moved":false,
            "static":false,
            "children":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

So I create my GridLayout recursively. It now looks like this:

```
<StyledGridLayout
            className="layout" 
            compactType={null}
            layout={layout}
            maxRows={gridRows}
            cols={gridCols}
            allowOverlap={true}
            width={gridWidth}
            margin={[0,0]}
            rowHeight={gridRowHeight}
            isDraggable={isDraggable}
            style={{ display: "flex" }}
             
            onLayoutChange={newLayout => {
                const newElemsList = [...options.elemsList]
                const tmpLayout = newLayout.map(item => ({
                    ...item, 
                    children: layout.find((i) => i.i === item.i).children,
                }))
                const activeElem = findChangedElement(newElemsList, tmpLayout)
                const targetLayout = findParent(newElemsList, activeElem)

                if (options.activeGrid === 0 && targetLayout === 0) {
                    setElemsList(tmpLayout)
                } else if (targetLayout !== 0) {
                    updateChildren(targetLayout, tmpLayout, newElemsList)
                    setElemsList(newElemsList)
                }
            }}
            onDragStart={onDragStart}
            onDragStop={onDragStop}
        >
            {layout.map((item) => {
                if (item?.children.length) {
                return (
                    <div
                        key={item.i}
                    >
                        { trimStringAfterSecondUnderscore(item.i) }
                        <CustomLayout      // the component renders itself recursively
                            layout={item.children}
                            gridCols={item.w}
                            gridRows={item.h}
                            gridRowHeight={gridRowHeight - 4}
                            gridWidth={item.w * 66}

                            onDragStart={() => {
                                setIsDraggable(false);
                            }}
                            onDragStop={() => {
                                setIsDraggable(true);
                            }}

                            options={options}
                            setActiveGrid={setActiveGrid}
                            setActive={setActive}
                            setSelectedComponent={setSelectedComponent}
                            setElemsList={setElemsList}
                        />
                    </div>
                    );
                } else {
                return (
                    <div 
                        key={item.i}
                    >
                        { trimStringAfterSecondUnderscore(item.i) }
                    </div>
                )}
            })}
        </StyledGridLayout>
```

My issue: this code works, but `onLayoutChange` handler doesn't get triggered when item of grid is being dragged (whether it is a main grid or o child grid). So I need to use the function which I use in `onLayoutChange` handler in `onDragStop` handler as well. But when I do so, I can no longer move items on child grid. What can I do about it? 
P.S. I'll leave a link on my codesanbox with a more simple example of my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-platform-pyfh37
I basically need to use setLayout function in my `onDragStop` handler, but I need to be still able to drag child elements. Thanks for help and explanations